# What kind of devices can be used to connect fiber optic segments via radio?

Tags: wireless

Say you want to connect building A to building B through a fiber optic cable, but at a given point, you are required to use a wireless connection (short range such as 10/20mt, where antennas are in sight), what kind of wireless devices can do this? Wireless repeaters? Or?

For instance:
[image]

Comment: wireless repeaters can do the trick but radio link devices will have better results. Wifi is half-duplex, while the radio link operates full-duplex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Various radio devices exist specifically for this.

As such low distance WiFi devices can do it, but their are usually not tailored for this role, as hinted by @kayaatabey.

It's better to use radio devices that are full duplex (using different frequencies for the two directions).

We have such a setup on a customer site with 180Mbs real throughput over radio between buildings 1.2km appart.

Note that radio frequencies usage is strictly regulated in most country and you must select products that operate at locally authorized frequencies.

Worth notice, a few years ago I also installed laser transmitters providing 100Mbs over 200m. Works well except in heavy fog.

Comment: Are you aware of ricetransmitting devices that can handle 10Gb/s speed?

Comment: @Riccardo Such products exist, just search for "10gbs radio" in your favorite search engine, but product recommendation is off-topic here (this could derail in so many way..)